# ¿como puedo hacer las fichas para un juego de damas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

mis compañeros y yo estamos creando un juego de damas con tkinter y me toco hacer la fichas pero el problema es que cada vez que lo imprimo me sale un circulo

```py
from tkinter import *
ventana = Tk()

can = Canvas(ventana, width=400, height=400)
ventana.geometry("500x500")

can.create_oval(100 , 70, 70 , 100 ,fill="gray")
can.grid(row=0,column=0)

can.create_oval(100 , 70, 70 , 100 ,fill="blue")
can.grid(row=1,column=2)

can.create_oval(100 , 70, 70 , 100 ,fill="yellow")
can.grid(row=4,column=4)


ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Si quieres hacer un juego en python, creo que sería mejor que usaras la librería pygame. https://www.pygame.org/news

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola y bienvenido a Stack overflow en español.

Primero debes saber que las figuras de tkinter no se ven influenciadas por el grid, ya que son dibujos en el canvas, no pertecen a la ventana directamente por lo que no se puede aplicar el atributo `.grid()`. `create_oval` retorna un número, el id del dibujo.

En su lugar, debes editar las coordenadas del dibujo.

```py
from tkinter import *
ventana = Tk()

can = Canvas(ventana, width=400, height=400)
ventana.geometry("500x500")
can.pack()

dama1 = can.create_oval(100, 70, 70, 100,fill="gray")

dama2 = can.create_oval(200, 70, 170, 100,fill="blue")

dama3 = can.create_oval(300, 70, 270, 100,fill="yellow")

ventana.mainloop()
```

Con esto he desplazado 100 unidades a la derecha cada círculo.

Hay que mencionar se usa las coordenadas del canvas no de la ventana, el canvas tiene su sistema de coordenadas donde dibuja (coordenadas relativas). Es decir, cambiar las coordenadas o el grid del canvas cambiará la de todos sus dibujos.

Si quieres mover un círculo ya creado debes usar la función del canvas `.move()`. Esta función la función añade o resta unidades a sus posición, es decir que si creaste el dibujo en la posición `100,100` y luego dices `move(10,10)` la posición final del dibujo será `110,110`, esto conviene mucho para crear animaciones o juegos.

```py
can.move(dama1,200,200) #Mover el circulo 200 en x, 200 en y
```

Es mucho más fácil así, puedes crear todas las damas en una sola ubicación, y luego moverlas a cada una de sus lugares. Y si quieres saber como destruir un dibujo, se hace con `.delete()`.

```py
can.delete(dama2)
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Comment: @JH84 he vuelto a editar la respuesta, corrigiendo algunas cosas respecto a la función `move()`